# Implementing "openssl passwd -1" in PHP

Tags: php, md5, php-openssl

The command "openssl passwd -1" uses MD5 based BSD password algorithm 1 to compute a string hash.

Example:

```
openssl passwd -1
$1$./j/us.N$P2tq6IkO0Zu2d3uqkEHpv.
```

How do I implement exactly the same functionality in PHP? I'd like it to be a native PHP function, rather than something return by exec/shell_exec.

Comment: Is [password hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) not good enough / better?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php does it serves?

Answer (score -2):

Example code

```
<?php
define('KEY', 'scret key');

function encrypt($value)
{
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $encrypt = openssl_encrypt($value, 'AES-128-CBC', KEY, 0, $iv);    
    return base64_encode($encrypt . ':::' . $iv);
}

function decrypt($data)
{
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    list($data, $iv) = explode(':::', $data);    
    return openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', KEY, 0, $iv);
}


$enc = encrypt('password');

echo decrypt($enc);
```

Comment: The question is for a hashing algorithm, this is an encyrption. If it can be decrypted, its not hashing.